# boostrap horizontal and vertical sections with easing scroll

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using the bootstrap template located here: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/scrolling-nav/

I like how the vertical scrolling is working. I want to use that and also create horizontal scrolling. So when you use the "top nav", the page will scroll vertical. Once you click a link or button in one of these "sections" it will scroll horizontal. 
The problem i face is how to have the sections align horizontal on one row.

any clue on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To stack sections horizontally (for example divs) use CSS property Float

```
div{
   float:left
}
```

DEMO : http://plnkr.co/edit/pLTus46XczbjQzMureTC?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I used an container div with width 200% and made the "sections" width 50% and float: left. Made a javascript to use the scrollLeft function and that did the trick.